# Android get straight line from GPS point in a specific direction

Tags: android, android-location

I would like to somehow retrieve an Object that represents a straight line from a lat/long and going in a specific direction. With this Object, I would like to be able to move along it at specified distances (10 meters forward or whatever I specify). This line doesn't have to circle the globe or anything, just go about 25 km from the original start point.

For example, I would like to do something like (not real code):

```
//startingLocation = GPS location object
double degrees = 98.1;//cardinal direction from this point (magnetic, could be converted to true)
LineObject line = new LineObject(startingLocation, degrees);
Location movedToLocation = line.move(5);//move 5 km up the line and return those GPS corrdinates as a Location
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "5 km away point: "+movedToLocation.latitude+" - "+movedToLocation.longitude);
```

How would this be possible?

Comment: There is a Polyline options on Google Maps API, you could just do the math to calculate the distance and the end point and just set a polyline with 2 points should be straight. Hope that helps.

Comment: A Polyline is a good start but it does not give me the option of drawing a line from a cardinal direction. This is where I am stuck

Comment: Yes you can, you just need to define the methos for example this two coords, are a straight line in north/south direction 39.95835, -101.54149 and 39.96835, -101.54149. Remember what latitude and longitude are, just do it as you would do with normal axis.